# Term for a series of connected lines that never fully close to create a shape?

Tags: geometry

In a design like the one below, the lines are proper lines without a defined width. 
What I'd like to know is what would a construct like this be referred to as mathematically?

Because:

1. It's more than just a line, but
2. Though it resembles a shape, it doesn't close in on itself to become one

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Foundations of geometry* Hilbert refers to these as **broken lines**. Take a look at the diagram for the hit for "broken lines" [on page 10](https://books.google.com/books?id=ulIGAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=foundations+of+geometry+broken+lines&source=bl&ots=tJ7kt8wvKi&sig=jQho0f-g4T5433f9U33F3rml7KQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCufL6l9zJAhXISyYKHYByBDcQ6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=broken%20lines&f=false) of this translation.

They are [also called "**piecewise linear arcs/curves**" or "**polygonal chains**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain).

I understand you were emphasizing the behaviors you wished to conclude when you mentioned having more than one path and the possibility of not closing. To be certain, I should note here that it would be totally fine to refer to a single line segment by any of these names too, or to such a thing that ends where it started by the same name. They would just be special cases. They aren't precluded.